# getElementById().value does not set the hidden input

Tags: javascript, jsf, hiddenfield

I am facing with an interesting situation. I am trying to set myValue from myBean as hidden input by using a javaScript code, but it does not work. I debugged and saw that it calls the getMyValue() method from myBean, and then does nothing. It does not give an error or warning and does not set the value. Any help please.

Thanks in advance. Code is below:

```
<h:body>

<script type="text/javascript">
   function setHiddenValue(){
   document.getElementById('myForm:hidden2').value = 3.0;
  }
</script>
<h:form id="myForm">            
   <h:inputHidden id="hidden2" value="#{myBean.myValue}" />
   <h:commandButton value="submit" action="..." onclick="setHiddenValue();" />
</h:form>

</h:body>
```

Comment: But it sure looks like the "id" value is just "hidden2", not "myform:hidden2".

Comment: Not really.. look at this `h:` prefixes.. I guess it's JSF that generates such id's.. Anyway please check if it is really the id that you have there generated..

Comment: @Pointy: you are wrong. Aylak, is this the *complete* code? There are so many possible reasons why the model value is not updated, but the code posted so far does not indicate in any way that the update model values phase would be skipped. This can for example happen when a validation/conversion error occurs.

Comment: @BalusC Yes it is. Besides this there is <xhtml> tag only which is necessary for xhtml file. But I have found the problem. I have searched in page source code and saw that the form's id is "form" not "myForm". I don't know how but it ignores my id and sets its own id for h:form which is "form".

Comment: Well, then you were apparently not running the code you think you were running. This can impossibly be caused by the code posted so far.

Comment: @BalusC ah OK; that was sort-of the point of the comment, because it seemed like there's missing information (or a tag).

Comment: I am. But in source code it puts form: in front of every tag id. For example it takes h:form like:         
<form id="form:myForm" name="form:myForm" method="post" action="/etkinlikmekani_yonetim/admin/config/mekanEdit.xhtml" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">

Comment: It's truly possible in some way (e.g. a composite component, or an include file nested in another form, etc), but definitely not by the code posted so far, assuming that it's the minimum necessary code which one could just copy'n'paste'n'run without changes to reproduce your problem (which after all thus isn't; be careful with oversimplifying code snippets in your future questions!).

Comment: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
   xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

Comment: It has the upper code at the top of the xhtml file.

Comment: I did not over simplified just tried something simple firstly for doing complex things later. Actually, I have copied this code here http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/how-to-pass-new-hidden-value-to-backing-bean-in-jsf/ (under **2. JSF Tag + JavaScript**) and just changed a little.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't button submiting the form instead of doing onclick action? Please try the same but using

```
<button onclick="setHiddenValue();">submit</button>
```

instead of

```
<h:commandButton value="submit" action="..." onclick="setHiddenValue();" />
```

or alternatively use:

```
<h:commandButton value="submit" action="..." onclick="setHiddenValue(); return false;" />
```

Comment: No it works fine like that. But the problem was it did not see my id for h:form. But I don't know how. Thanks anyway.